# How to get the different items from the list in flutter?

Tags: list, flutter

I have a list like this,
`List<String> subjects = ["Math", "Science" ,"Health","Social","Programming", "Math","Social"]`
Now from this list, how to get the different subjects' names, if one of the subjects is repeated, we shall get only one of the values of that item.
**How to do that?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just iterate through all the elements and find whether it is repeating.

Or else, you can make you of `Set` in dart.

```
List<String> subjects = ["Math", "Science" ,"Health","Social","Programming", "Math","Social"];
  
var uniqueValues = new Set.from(subjects);
print(uniqueValues.toList());
```

**Output:**

```
[Math, Science, Health, Social, Programming]
```

Reference: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.1/dart-core/Set-class.html

Hope that solves your issue.